# How can I use the \angle command and produce the - character in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I need to be able to use the \angle command and produce the - character in my presentation, but they dont seem to work quite right in beamer.  the \angle command produces nothing in the pdf, and the - character produces the * character in the pdf.  Anyone know how I can change this?

Here is some code from my presentation that doesnt quite work the way that I would like it to:

```
\begin{theorem}
In neutral geometry, for any triangle $\triangle ABC$ there exists a triangle $\triangle A_1B_1C_1$ such that the two triangles have the same angle sums but $m\angle A_1 \leq \frac{1}{2} (m\angle A)$.
\end{theorem}

\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have found!

`\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{theorem}
In neutral geometry, for any triangle $\triangle ABC$ there exists a triangle $\triangle A_1B_1C_1$ such that the two triangles have the same angle sums but $m\angle A_1 \leq \frac{1}{2} (m\angle A)$.
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

[image]

Does it satisfy your requirements?

Greetings :)

Comment: I need to be able to produce the theorem like that but in the beamer class, not the article class

Comment: @BradenCarlson Please check now. :)

Comment: ah yes I got it.  It turns out if one uses the stix package along with the amsmath package in beamer it messes things up. Thanks!

Comment: @BradenCarlson you are welcome. Would you mind accepting and upvoting the answer? ty too